# Select all not working in ExtJS textfield

Tags: extjs4, selectall

I'm working on a large single page app that uses ExtJS 4. One very annoying issue that pervades the app is that when a user tries to trigger a select all within a textfield (or other text input box), nothing happens.

This can be done either by hitting Cmd-A or by clicking Edit > Select All within the browser.

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. It might not even be ExtJS's fault.. Maybe it is some CSS that is preventing this from working or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just so everyone know's what I mean when I say textfield, they look like this:

[image: example textfield]

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide some code and possible css that might(you think) preventing this.

Comment: I wish I could, but I really have no idea where that css/code would even exist... somewhere in an enormous sprawling app... I'm hoping someone else had a similar issue and figured out a solution/what was causing it.